# How do I copy the Recovery Partition to a USB and make that a bootable drive, in order to reinstall the OS?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, partitioning, windows-vista

I have copied all the data in a hidden OS recovery partition from a hard drive. This partition was provided by the laptop manufacturer to restore the laptop to its original factory **Vista** installation.

**How do I copy this data onto a flash USB drive and then restore the OS from the USB drive?**

Do I need to make the USB drive bootable, then copy the data to the USB drive and boot from the USB drive?

I really wonder what the use of all these recovery partitions ***IS***, when they are not reachable because they are hidden, or simply don't work. Here's what I already tried:

1. Unhide the hidden partition with Partition Magic on Hiren's BootCD
2. Reduced the partition in size somewhat so that it will fit on a USB
3. Did disk-to-disk copy with DriveImageXML to a USB

This is where I got stuck because the USB isn't bootable at all.

If you managed to make the USB bootable, please let me know how.

I've checked out similar answers and they either didn't work or I already tried them unsuccessfully.

Comment: Is your USB drive formatted as NTFS or FAT32? Is it partitioned as MBR or GPT?

Comment: USB is FAT32 and mbr. I think. It's made with Rufus-2.6p and DriveImageXML

Comment: Can you run `bootsect /nt60 L:` (where L is the drive USB drive letter) and try booting from it?